# Why is my set data with useState not updating the state?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, setstate

setAcessKeys is not updating the state immediately even though the data is available at that point which I know through the console.log(data) or by passing the array manually. I realized that without useEffect, it renders multiple times and the console.log(accessKeys) returns data from the third run going.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import AccessKey from "./AccessKey";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "./AccessKey.module.css";

const AccessKeys = () => {
  const [accessKeys, setAccessKeys] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getAccessKeys = async () => {
      try {
        let token = localStorage.getItem("auth");
        const response = await axios.get(
          "http://localhost:5000/api/keys/user",
          {
            headers: {
              authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );

        const data = response.data;

        console.log(data); // [{...}, {...}]

        setAccessKeys((prevKeys) => [...prevKeys, ...data]);

        console.log(accessKeys); // []
      } catch (error) {
        navigate("/");
        toast.error(error.response.data.message);
      }
    };

    getAccessKeys();
  }, [navigate, accessKeys]);

  return (
    <>
      {accessKeys.length > 0 ? (
        <main>
          {accessKeys.map((accessKey) => (
            <AccessKey key={accessKey._id} acesskey={accessKey} />
          ))}
        </main>
      ) : (
        <h4>You do not have any Access Keys at the moment</h4>
      )}
    </>
  );
};

export default AccessKeys;
```

Comment: React state changes are asynchronous, you can't log their changes on the next line. Print state in the main body of the function so get it's value on latest render

Comment: How do I print state in the main body of the function?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54069253/the-usestate-set-method-is-not-reflecting-a-change-immediately?rq=1

Comment: That didn't  work for me

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. I found out it was a spelling mistake in one of my components.